# How to give specific file location as an argument to writeBin() method in R?

Tags: r, download, location

the file which is downloaded by `writeBin()` is saved at the current location. but I want to save it at another location either in sub-directories in the current location or somewhere else. 
`writeBin(downlaod$response$content, "Inventory.csv")` This is line of code. suppose i want to save the **inventory.csv** at location **"current_directory/download_folder"**.

or here, I am trying to download CSV file using the following script:

```
url <- "https://lgloz050.lss.emc.com:58443/APG/"
dn_url <- "https://lgloz050.lss.emc.com:58443/APG/lookup/Report%20Library/Amazon%20S3/Inventory/Accounts/report.csv"

session <-  html_session(url) 
form <- html_form(session)[[1]]
 fl_fm <- set_values(form,
                     j_username = "***",
                     j_password = "***")
 main_page <- submit_form(session, fl_fm) 
 downlaod <- jump_to(main_page,cfig$dn_url)
 writeBin(downlaod$response$content, "Inventory.csv" )
```

Can I use **writeBin()** if not then, Is there any alternative method of **writeBin()** or some another way to download the CSV file from **https site** which requires a login?

Thanks in advance for suggestions!!!

Comment: Does this work? `writeBin(downlaod$response$content, "current_directory/download_folder/Inventory.csv" )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the help file of a function using `?writeBin` or `help(writeBin)`. In here you see that the argument you are looking for is `con`:

> writeBin(object, con, size = NA_integer_,
>            endian = .Platform$endian, useBytes = FALSE)
>
> con   A connection object or a character string naming a file or a raw vector.

Now you can just supply any location to the `con` argument, pretty much like you already did:

```
writeBin(object = downlaod$response$content, 
         con = "./download_folder/Inventory.csv" )
```

The only thing you have to keep in mind is that `R` is expecting absolute paths here, which means your path will look like this:

```
/home/user/current_directory/download_folder/Inventory.csv
```

On a Linux machine or like this:

```
C:/user/Documents/current_directory/download_folder/Inventory.csv
```

On Windows.

You can also use paths relative to your current working directory (and I assumed you did above) by substituting `current_directory/` with `./`:

```
./download_folder/Inventory.csv
```

Or even go one folder up from your directory:

```
../current_directory/download_folder/Inventory.csv
```

Or two:

```
../../current_directory/download_folder/Inventory.csv
```

Comment: awesome suggestion, it works accordingly. Is there some other method to do the same?